# how to broadcast to local instance only when using the redis-adapter?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

It's possible to add the local flag when emitting to a room

```
// sending to all clients on this node (when using multiple nodes)
io.to(channel).local
  .emit(message.event, channel, message.data)
```

However, when broadcasting from a socket instance it's not possible to add a local flag is there any way to achieve the same behaviour?

**this wont work**

```
socket.broadcast.to(channel).local
  .emit(message.event, channel, message.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure,but you can try something like this

```
 io.sockets.in(room_id).emit('')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `local` flag is intended for that: https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/#Flag-%E2%80%98local%E2%80%99

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to broadcast to a local instance which uses redis-adapter but also excludes the sender?

`io.local.emit()` will broadcast to clients that are connected to the current server but it also includes the sender.

`socket.broadcast.emit()` broadcasts to clients across all servers excluding the sender.